# Make a png in a jar file android

Tags: java, android, jar, png, getresource

I'm trying to use a png file in my jar using `getClass().getResourceAsStream("mypngfile.png")`

I tried many things found on the internet but nothing helped. I think the issue is that the png is not included in my jar.  I'm using a full android build and when going into `out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/myjarname_intermediates/classes/my/package/..`
It looks like all my classes are there except for the png.

I also tried opening the jar in eclipse and using tar -tvf but i couldn't even see the classes there. Probably has to do with the way android compiles the jars without the code itself?

I think I need to change my Android.mk file somehow so that the png is compiled and added to the build.

my android.mk looks like this:

```
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := src/files...  \
                   src/my/package/pen.png 


LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES  := src/my/package/pen.png \
                           res/drawable-xhdpi/pen.png 
LOCAL_MODULE := MyLibName

include $(BUILD_JAVA_LIBRARY)`
```

How do I change the android.mk so that the png is compiled and inserted into the jar?

Comment: why you don't use an assets folder and AssetManager class ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#%21topic/android-building/w8P7GyT5YjE

I needed to add `LOCAL_JAVA_RESOURCE_DIRS :=` with the resources directories to my png files and they are finally packaged with the jar file!

hope this helps everyone else.